# ssvncviewer copy/paste?

Tags: xorg, vnc, vncviewer

I'm running the ssvncviewer against x1vnc, ubuntu on both sides. I've trying to use the F8 menu to copy paste. Neither local to or from remote seem to work. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I also have problems with `ssvncviewer` and copy paste as well; some things that sometimes work for me:

- If copy/paste of text fails from local to remote: F8, then click `Clipboard: local -> remote`, and then again Ctrl-C local, then switch to remote, then Ctrl-V on remote
- If copy/paste of text fails from remote to local: exit `ssvncviewer`, and start it again using the `-sendclipboard` command line option (see https://helpmanual.io/help/ssvncviewer/ ); switch to remote, Ctrl-C to copy your text; switch to local, Ctrl-V to paste

There might be also problems with the VNC server setup, whatever it is - so you might want to test the same server with multiple other VNC clients, and see how copy/paste goes